# MySQL ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'column1-column2' for key 'duplicate_data' when trying to set ROW_FORMAT to Compressed

Tags: mysql, indexing

When I try to compress my MySQL table using

```
alter table myTableName row_format=COMPRESSED;
```

I get the error

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1123-7537-2020' for key 'duplicate_data'
```

I have an index "duplicate_data" which I use to prevent duplicate rows when 3 fields are identical for a row.
When I search for this combination I cannot find it in the database and when I run the compress command again, I get another "Duplicate entry" error with other data.

How can I fix this? Is there a way to search for this kind of duplicate data (which actually should have been prevented by the index anyway)

**Edit**: After finding this https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=104608 I could run the command successfully by using:

```
ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED, ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=SHARED
```

This explains why:

> When running an in-place online DDL operation, the thread that runs
> the ALTER TABLE statement applies an online log of DML operations that
> were run concurrently on the same table from other connection threads.
> When the DML operations are applied, it is possible to encounter a
> duplicate key entry error (ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry), even
> if the duplicate entry is only temporary and would be reverted by a
> later entry in the online log. This is similar to the idea of a
> foreign key constraint check in InnoDB in which constraints must hold
> during a transaction.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

You found the explanation of why it happens in the bug log.

Fixing it could be done by forcing the ALTER TABLE to be blocking:

```
ALTER TABLE myTableName ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED, ALGORITHM=COPY;
```

But this will not allow concurrent DML, so prepare for the table to be inaccessible to the application until the ALTER is done.

Or you could use a different online DDL solution such as [pt-online-schema-change](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-online-schema-change.html). Since all DML changes are performed synchronously to both the original table and the copy table through triggers, there should be no issue with duplicate keys. However, there are other cases where pt-osc can cause issues.

It just goes to prove [TANSTAAFL](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TANSTAAFL) — *There Ain't No Such Thing As A Free Lunch.* It's practically not possible to have unhindered usage of the table while it is being restructured.